# Cannot hit AspNetCore 3.1 MVC API endpoints when published

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-routing

AspNetCore 3.1 MVC API. Conventional startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

I can hit all endpoints when running on localhost. When I publish, all endpoints return 404.

To test I am publishing to the correct location, I added an endpoint that displays in the browser

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Content("Users Index");
}
```

When I browse to `https://subweb.mainweb/users/api/users/index`I see `Users Index` returned in the browser, but all other endpoints return 404.

The controller is decorated

```
[Route("api/Users/[action]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
```

All other endpoints are decorated eg

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName(nameof(IsRegisteredUser))]
public IActionResult IsRegisteredUser()
```

But I don't see how this would make a difference between running locally and on the server.

How could it be that all endpoints are available in localhost, but only the test endpoint when published? Where do I begin to look?

Comment: Please double check the request url you entered, it might look like `https://subweb.mainweb/users/api/users/IsRegisteredUser`, do not miss "**users**" before `/api/users/[action]`. Besides, please check if any rewrite rule(s) are applied to your site/app on your server.

Comment: @Fei Han you have an eagle eye! It was a missing users. Please propose as answer so I can accept.

Comment: Hi @Vague, glad to hear it did help resolve the issue. And I have post it as answer, hoping it can help other community members quickly resolve similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I browse to https://subweb.mainweb/users/api/users/indexI see Users Index returned in the browser, but all other endpoints return 404.

Based on your above example URL, it seems that you host your ASP.NET Core Web API app as an sub-application (sub-app) at `/users` on your server.

To access the endpoint(s), you should make sure you include the sub-app's pathbase in URL, otherwise it would result in a 404 - Not Found error.